# AS3 Packager for iPhone: Can the app download content?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, mobile, packager-for-iphone

I am in the stages of designing a magazine concept for a client, taking the printed version and adding animated and interactive content, it seems Flash would be the obvious choice, and something which I am reasonably skilled with.

**If I build the Magazine app with Flash, will the app be able to download additional issues?** if so please point to any resources on the subject if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/) to get Flash content on an iOS device. However, you can't download compiled Flash files (.swf) to the iOS device and execute them after the app has been installed.

From the [developer documentation](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/packagerforiphone/packagerforiphone_devguide.pdf):

> Loader
>
> In an iPhone application, you cannot
> use the Loader.load() method. However,
> you cannot run any ActionScript code
> in SWF content loaded with the
> Loader.load() method. However, you can
> use assets in the SWF file (such as
> movie clips, images, fonts, and sounds
> in the library). You can also use the
> Loader.load() method to load image
> files

If you would like to use InDesign and some of the other tools that Adobe Makes, you can consider the so called [Digital Publishing Suite](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitalpublishingsuite/) which is a toolset that was used to make some of the iPad magazines such as Wired or Martha Stewart Living.

Comment: great thanks for the info, and link exactly what I needed to find. Do you know if File.createTempFile() and File.createTempDirectory() are really temporary like they say? ideally I would need the app to create a folder 'issue2', and then files 'page1.jpg', 'page2.jpg' etc

Comment: If you want to store files permanently you will want to create files in `File.applicationStorageDirectory` location. These should be permanent as long as the user doesn't delete your application.